# pandas - replace/delete part from every row in one column that is in other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 columns - df["_1"] and df["_2"].
df["_1"]:

```
1. ananas patrzy
2. socja lizmzwyci ęży
```

df["_2"]:

```
1. patrzy
2. ęży
```

What I want to do is to delete those parts in df_1 that are in relevant row in df_2. So the result should be like:

df["_3"]

```
1. ananas
2. socja lizmzwyci
```

What I tried:

```
1. df.apply(lambda x:  x["_1"].replace(x["_2"], ''),axis=1) # doesn't work
2. df["_1"].str.strip( df["_2"].str) # - tried also with rstrip - doesn't work either
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: df["_1"].replace(df["_2"].str, '') or df["_1"].replace(df["_2"], '')  also didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you need is:

```
df['_1'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['_1'].replace(row['_2'], ''), axis='columns')
```

To remove any leading/trailing spaces, add a `.str.strip()`:

```
df['_1'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['_1'].replace(row['_2'], ''), axis='columns').str.strip()
```